# Build source code of OS to work on pi

Tags: pi-2, cross-compilation

I have raspberry-pi 2 And i want to Build tails OS to work on it
I downloaded the source code and installed cmake and gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi but i have no idea how to do that.
I searched online but i found myself stuck with lot of links talking about thing called cross-compilation but i don't know what is they talking about!?
Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tails OS does no run on the Pi. Per the Tails OS [FAQ](https://tails.boum.org/support/faq/index.en.html#index7h2):

> Does Tails work on ARM architecture, Raspberry Pi, or tablets? For the
>   moment, Tails is only available on the x86 and x86_64 architectures.
>   The Raspberry Pi and many tablets are based on the ARM architecture.
>   Tails does not work on the ARM architecture so far. Look for a tablet
>   with an AMD or Intel processor. Try to verify its compatibility with
>   Debian beforehand, for example make sure that the Wi-Fi interface is
>   supported.

cross compilation means compiling on a different machine or architecture than the code will run on. For example compiling tails on your PC for use on your Pi.